# how to add button in data table so , that the particular column can be edited

Tags: javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
        //"ajax": "jsonArray.txt",

         "ajax" :{
            "url" : "jsonArray.txt",
            "dataSrc" :"caseList"

         },
        "columns": [
        { "data": "caseId" },
        { "data": "accountId" },
        { "data": "createdBy" },
        { "data": "caseCreationDate" },
        { "data": "serialNo" },
        { "data": "productLine" },
        { "data": "caseStatus" },
        { "data": "description" }
    ],
      "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {          
        var addButton = '<a name="caseid" data-PLName="'+aData["plShortName"]+'" data-caseId="'+aData["caseId"]+'" class="caseNo">'+aData["caseId"]+'</a>';
       $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(addButton);
       }


} );
} );
```

This, is the piece of code which i have written for the data table,Its not working for me..kindly tell me where the problem is. and the right way to write this code.

Comment: please read about the tag before adding it `Java (not to be confused with JavaScript)`

Comment: Please be more specific than "*Its not working for me*". Thanks.

Comment: Note: If you want the answer then stick around for few minutes after posting the question dont just post the question and run away.It would be benificial for you only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant not directly write your `ajax` call instead use `datatable` `"sAjaxSource": url` attribute, or use `oSettings.jqXHR` to write your custom `ajax call`

```
oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success": fnCallback
                });
```